# jquery.mmenu how to use the extensions with npm

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I use jquery.mmenu with npm so I import it with: `import 'jquery.mmenu';`.
Now I need to use a extension of sais jquery Plugin as well. Therefore I wanted to import this like so:

```
import 'jquery.mmenu.fixedelements';
```

But this does not work:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery.mmenu.fixedelements'

javascript imports are a totaly mistery anyway.

How do I have to import this properly?

I tried tings like import with relative path's `'/dist/addons/fixedelements/jquery.mmenu.fidexelements';` but this doesn't work as well.

Comment: It depends on your build tool, but I'd give `import 'jquery.mmenu/dist/addons/fixedelements/jquery.mmenu.fidexelements'` a try.
If you use Webpack or Rollup.js, you could set an alias. ```'jquery.mmenu.fixedelements': require.resolve('jquery.mmenu/dist/addons/fixedelements/jquery.mmenu.fidexelements')```. You could reference such a module as you initially wanted to, using `import 'jquery.mmenu.fixedelements';`

Comment: I use webpack as a build tool